# How can a std::vector name be treated like a C-type array name?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

In C, it is easy to do something like:

```
int foo (int arr[], int size) {

    // Do some stuff.

    // Recur ignoring half of the input array.
    return foo (arr + size / 2, size / 2);
}
```

I know that we are able to do that because in C, the name of array is basically a pointer to a contiguous block in the memory and basic pointer arithmetic works just fine with it.

My question is that how do I achieve this kind of convenience with C++ vector or array containers? Are there any alternative trick to do just that, fundamentally?

From what I know, this wouldn't work at all:

```
int foo (vector<int>& arr, int size) {

    // Do some stuff.

    // Recur ignoring half of the input array.
    return foo (arr + size / 2, size / 2);
}
```

Comment: Pass iterators of begin and end of needed chunk

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Yes, that is possible but what if I don't have freedom to change function signature?

Comment: If you have a `std::vector` you don't need to pass the size. And if you have a range of iterators, it can be calculated.

Comment: Talking about the size, the functions you show have a very bad bug: You recurse using "half" the array, but still pass the full size.

Comment: @Duh call it like this `foo(vec.data(), vec.size())`. And [read some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is just an example. Please, try to focus on underlying question.

Comment: *"the name of array is basically a pointer to a contiguous block in the memory"* No it's not. But `arr` inside `foo` actually *is* a pointer and not an array.

Comment: If there are errors or bugs in the code it distracts from the actual problem you want help with. If you show pseudo-code then you should explicitly say so.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Bug's fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Why can't you change the signature? Obviously I don't know what you want to do with the function but it seems in maintaining that signature you're unnecessarily passing data around and limit the generic-nus of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the function signature than you can pass the vector's `data()` and `size()` properties, which are compatible with the function:

```
foo(v.data(), v.size());
```

Comment: Your answer addresses the exact question I asked. However, I'd still need to make a change in the function signature because [vector::data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) returns a pointer to the memory block used by the vector.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. `std::vector<int>::data()` and `int[]` are compatible - remember that the array has decayed to a pointer when it gets to the function. It compiles fine for me.

Comment: May be you didn't notice; `arr` is declared as a vector not an array of ints as `int[]`. Besides, your comment confuses me because since I'm recurring the same function and `arr` is a vector I get to use `::data()` but from your last comment it appears that you were assuming `arr` to be of type `int[]` in the first place. Can you clarify?

Comment: I may have been a bit confused. I thought you wanted a function like your first  C function where `arr` is `int[]`. You can send `std::vector<int>::data() to this.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ solution is to think in terms of the objects you are using. A `vector`

So, you could simply use an iterator and do things like:

```
arr.begin()
arr.begin()+(size/2)
```

In other words: instead of pushing the C concept onto C++ use the corresponding C++ concept.

In this case, you can use [iterators](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterators.html) to make "parts" of your array "available" to the outside worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with a `std::vector<int>`, the obvious answer is not to change the function at all.

Simply call it differently.

```
 foo(&some_vector[0], some_vector.size());    // assume some_vector is not const
```

This will pass a pointer to the first element and the size of `some_vector` to your C-style `foo()`.  Since elements of a `std::vector` are guaranteed to be contiguous, this will work as you request.

Personally, however, I wouldn't do that.   I'd use iterators

```
 #include <iterator>

 int foo (std::vector<int>::iterator begin, std::vector<int>::iterator end)
 {

     // Do some stuff.

     // Recur ignoring half of the input array.

    std::advance(begin, std::distance(begin, end)/2);
    return foo (begin, end);
 }

 //  to call it

 foo(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end());
```

You obviously need some logic to avoid infinite recursion in the function.  But that is true of the function you started with.

Templates allow this to me made both simpler and more general, since it is not necessary to hard-code assumptions about the iterators (or what type of container they come from)

```
 #include <iterator>

 template<class Iterator>
 int foo (Iterator begin, Iterator end)
 {

     // Do some stuff.

     // Recur ignoring half of the input array.

    std::advance(begin, std::distance(begin, end)/2);
    return foo (begin, end);
 }

 // call like before
```

The requirements of `std::advance()` and `std::distance()` are pretty minimal - essentially that the iterators are what the standard calls *input iterators* (which means that they can be used in sequential input operations, where each value pointed by the iterator is read only once and then the iterator is incremented).    Your "Do some stuff" code might introduce more restrictive requirements though.